# next.js 13 stuck in fast refresh loop on chrome

Tags: next.js13, fast-refresh

I've been following along a tutorial from Papa react on next13 and I'm getting the strangest error. I get to timestamp 06:02 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aP9nyTcd44 after deleting the stock index.js page and I get the fast refresh loop on in terminal of vsc and another error in chrome console. I cannot understand what is happening.

Github link:https://github.com/ieUlysses/automatic-fiesta

console printouts of chrome and vsc console are below.
Thank you in advance

[image: screenshots of error message]

Answer (score 2):

This was a strange error - probably related to the version I was using

**FIX:**

Fast refresh worked again normally after I **disabled the cache** in the **network inspector** and **reloaded the page** (then immediately re-enabled after it was working again):

[image]

**You might** also need to clear the site data in the application inspector, which I did 1000 times before the step above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error with one of my apps.  It took me a while to figure out but it worked by stopping and restarting it in the terminal.  I hope you had figured it out by now.  If not, try restarting your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34388008)